# Topic models evaluation in Gensim

Tags: python, topic-models, natural-language

I've been experimenting with LDA topic modelling using [Gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/). I couldn't seem to find any topic model evaluation facility in Gensim, which could report on the perplexity of a topic model on held-out evaluation texts thus facilitates subsequent fine tuning of LDA parameters (e.g. number of topics). It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could shed some light on how I can perform topic model evaluation in Gensim. This question had also been posted on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615951/topic-models-evaluation-in-gensim).

Answer (score 3):

Found the [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/LM619SB57zM) on the [gensim mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gensim).

In short, the bound() method of LdaModel computes a lower bound on perplexity, based on a held-out corpus.

Answer (score 3):

This seemingly recent (and great) addition to GitHub by Markus Konrad seems to address MANY Topic Modeling evaluation problems:

tmtoolkit - Text Mining and Topic modeling tool kit:

https://github.com/WZBSocialScienceCenter/tmtoolkit